# Calculated fields across different lines in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql

The reason for this is complicated and won't over do it, but I'm doing a costing report based on a bill of materials.

```
BOMID       ItemID       Qty         Height    Width   Depth            Price
111         component    2                                              0
component   wood         1           100       100     10               £3.69
```

So as you can see, the Bill of materials for this item is called a `111` and within it, it uses `2 x` a component. the line below is the details of that component.So for each item, the price is `3.69`.

What I need is a way of calculating the `3.39` by the quantity of 2 on the above line. the rule here is the `ItemID` always has a matching `BOMID` for its components.

I've tried to generalize the data to make it simpler to understand.

Comment: show us expected output

Comment: something similar to the above really but with a field 'Total price' showing the price * Qty of the itemid that matches the bomID

Comment: But you want to show both rows??

Comment: Is this output ok for you???? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/742b7/7

Comment: That output is spot on!

Comment: OK.. so I have tested my query, and got it working with your help thanks kindly.

Comment: can you please accept my answer below? dont reply to my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do self join

```
select  *,(a.Qty * a.Price) as col1 from test a  join test b on a.BOMID = b.ItemId
```

Here is [Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/742b7/7)

Comment: Hi sorry, I'm pretty new to the site, accepted it as the answer, my query turned out to be quite impressive for an "enthusiastic amateur! used some good functions like CTE and the self join as you mentioned then lots of calculated fields :) thanks a million!

Comment: @JustAnAverageSQLuser Thats good that you used many other variations